# visual comparision of pages in different browsers

Tags: html, cross-browser, comparison, webpage-screenshot

I want to test my html page visually in every browser like chrome FF and IE, like the position of all the elements and padding and margin in the page is correct or not.

Now what I am doing is I open the page in two browsers and I cascade the two browsers side by side and I compared it with my eyes.

Now my question is : is there any tool or plugin available to test the page by overlapping the page in IE with the same page in chrome or FF so that I can find any difference in visual representation of the elements, so that I could correct it.
Just like screen shot comparison (in screenshot comparison I can't compare the entire page and moreover I can't overlap one screenshot images one over another)?

Answer (score -1):

This is the wrong way to go about it. Attempting to get each browser to match pixel-for-pixel is a futile endeavor and only leads to frustration, code bloat, and wasted effort.

Design for the valid browsers (typically the Webkit ones and Firefox). Then fix, as needed for the others. But don't try to get things to mesh pixel for pixel.